# How do I pop the last elements of lists nested in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am manipulating the following dataframe:

```
      CaseID                Activities
0          0        [10, 16, 577, 250]
1          1   [355, 10, 16, 577, 578]
2          2  [355, 578, 578, 16, 578]
3          3  [355, 12, 546, 438, 578]
4          4    [577, 180, 12, 79, 78]
```

my goal is to delete the last element of each list, so *250* for Case0, *578* for Case1 etc.

The following code works for a single row:

```
df.loc[0, 'Activities'].pop()
```

However, as soon as I try to iterate over the dataframe to pop the last list element in every row, I get a
*TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'*

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[row, 'Activities'].pop()
```

Comment: what do you want to do here? Just delete or use the elements in a loop?

Comment: Why are you doing `df.loc[row, 'Activities']`? Why did you put `row` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Activities"] = df["Activities"].str[:-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   CaseID           Activities
0       0        [10, 16, 577]
1       1   [355, 10, 16, 577]
2       2  [355, 578, 578, 16]
3       3  [355, 12, 546, 438]
4       4   [577, 180, 12, 79]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have lists, you do not need to iterate the whole DataFrame, just use the Series (column):

```
for l in df['Activities']:
    print(l.pop())
print(df)
```

output:

```
250
578
578
578
78
   CaseID           Activities
0       0        [10, 16, 577]
1       1   [355, 10, 16, 577]
2       2  [355, 578, 578, 16]
3       3  [355, 12, 546, 438]
4       4   [577, 180, 12, 79]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way but this preserves the original format. We first `explode` the lists into a single column keeping the original index, then we `groupby` the original index keeping every row but the last. Lastly we `groupby` the original index once more and aggregate the results back in to a `list`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "CaseID": [0, 1, 2],
        "Activities": [
            [10, 16, 577, 250],
            [355, 10, 16, 577, 578],
            [355, 578, 578, 16, 578],
        ],
    }
)

df.assign(
    Activities=df.Activities.explode()
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("index", as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda s: s.head(len(s) - 1))
    .groupby("index")["Activities"]
    .apply(list)
)

   CaseID           Activities
0       0        [10, 16, 577]
1       1   [355, 10, 16, 577]
2       2  [355, 578, 578, 16]
```